# C# DataGridView not populating from a separate form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm sorry if my title is bad, its 1:30am and I'm all out of coffee. I've tried a few solutions suggested on similar questions but I can't figure it out as my case is a little different.

I'm trying to use a separate form to select parameters for the method I use to format data which is passed to a DataGridView in the original form, however its not populating the DataGridView. I have set the new form to be a dialog, it receives the original form reference when its called, on the form there is a DateTimePicker and a button, when the button is clicked it calls a method that gets the datetime value, then it calls a method on the original form with the datetime parameters being passed to it and closes the dialog. The method on the original form runs with the parameters that where passed to get the data for the DataGridView and then calls the datasource method passing the bindinglist to it.

This method of filling the DataGridView using a dialog is my best interpretation of how its been explained in similar questions on this site but its not populating my DataGridView. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchDialog search = new SearchDialog(this);
        search.Show();
    }
```

)button2 is a cancel button(

```
public partial class SearchDialog : Form
{
    static DirectoryInfo DexFolder = new DirectoryInfo(Properties.Settings.Default.DexFolderPath);
    static DirectoryInfo ExcelFile = new DirectoryInfo(Properties.Settings.Default.ExcelFilePath);

    public SearchDialog(Main form)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fromDateSelector.Checked = false;
        toDateSelector.Checked = false;
        MainForm = form;
    }

    public Main MainForm {get; set;}

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchParameters();
        Close();
    }

    private void SearchParameters()
    {
        DateTime allTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-150);
        DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
        if (fromDateSelector.Checked == true)
        {
            allTime = fromDateSelector.Value;
        }
        if (toDateSelector.Checked == true)
        {
            current = toDateSelector.Value;
        }
        MainForm.GetFiles(DexFolder, current, allTime);
    }
}
```

(back on Main form)

```
public void GetFiles(DirectoryInfo FilePath, DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        List<string> DexFileNames = new List<string>();
        List<string> DexData = new List<string>();
        IList<FileManagerView> fileManagerData = new BindingList<FileManagerView>();

        string[] ExcelData = File.ReadAllLines(ExcelFile.ToString());

        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in FilePath.GetFiles("*.dex"))
        {
            DexFileNames.Add(fileInfo.Name);
        }

        foreach (string DexFileName in DexFileNames)
        {
            DateTime dexDate = File.GetCreationTime(FilePath + DexFileName);
            string[] NameData = DexFileName.Split('_', '-', '.');
            if (NameData.Length > 2)
            {
                dexDate = DateTime.ParseExact(NameData[1] + NameData[2], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            string DexPHYSID = NameData[0];
            string machineNumber = "";
            string machineLocation = "";
            string telemetryDevice = "";
            string routeNumber = "";
            string machinePHYSID = "";
            string driverName = "";

            foreach (string line in ExcelData)
            {
                string[] lineData = line.Split(',');
                if (DexPHYSID == lineData[14].Trim('"'))
                {
                    machinePHYSID = lineData[14].Trim('"');
                    machineNumber = lineData[0].Trim('"');
                    machineLocation = lineData[2].Trim('"');
                    string RouteNumberFull = lineData[17].Trim('"');
                    string[] DriverName = lineData[18].Trim('"').Split('(');
                    telemetryDevice = lineData[8].Trim('"');
                    string[] RouteNumberData = RouteNumberFull.Split(' ');
                    driverName = DriverName[0];
                    try
                    {
                        routeNumber = RouteNumberData[1] + " " + RouteNumberData[2];
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            if (DexPHYSID == machinePHYSID)
            {
                FileManagerView fileManagerView = new FileManagerView();


                if (dexDate.ToString("dd-MM-yy") == from.ToString("dd-MM-yy") && dexDate.ToString("dd-MM-yy") == to.ToString("dd-MM-yy"))
                {
                    fileManagerView.machineNumber = machineNumber;
                    fileManagerView.machineLocation = machineLocation;
                    fileManagerView.telemetryDevice = telemetryDevice;
                    fileManagerView.physid = DexPHYSID;
                    fileManagerView.routeNumber = routeNumber;
                    fileManagerView.date = dexDate;
                    fileManagerView.driver = driverName;
                    fileManagerData.Add(fileManagerView);
                }
            }
        }

        FileManagerPopulate(fileManagerData);
    }

    public class FileManagerView
    {
        public string machineNumber { get; set; }
        public string machineLocation { get; set; }
        public string telemetryDevice { get; set; }
        public string physid { get; set; }
        public string routeNumber { get; set; }
        public string driver { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }

    public void FileManagerPopulate(IList<FileManagerView> data)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Comment: You might notice the from/to datetimes are mixed up, this is just because I was testing the possibility that I mixed them up :)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was the use of == operands instead of > and < when the GetFiles() method was checking if the file date was within the selected range.

I'm going to leave this here as it may help someone else looking for answers.